# WAMP : MYSQL running super slow

Tags: mysql, wamp

The nightmare started 2 days ago, when I was using WAMP local server to work on my website (Im using W7 32bit). About 3 or 4 years, everything was working fine. But suddenly, without any abvious reason server (I think its mysql) started to run very very slow, some pages doesnt even load at all, or load after a 2-5 min delay. Before - it took maximum of 5 sec. The problem is persistant with any website I tried, wich uses a lot of queries.

I tried restarting, and reinstalling WAMP. No luck - problem still remains. 
All the WAMP settings are default. No changes to websites were made. It's driving me crazy. mysqld.exe process eats up like 430 MB of memory, upon first load of WAMP.

I even tried to reinstall windows - no luck. Has anyone have an idea, what is going on? How can WAMP suddenly crash, without any reason?

Any ideas will be appriciated. I can provide any information you may need to help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try rolling back windows updates?  There was a recent update that affected SQLlite; maybe this is related.

Comment: check your HDD maybe it is damagged

Comment: I did a clean installation of windows 7 today. And I didnt do any updates. I tried my external HDD and internal - no luck. :(